# randomly assign clusters using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I know I can use randomizr for clustered random assignment using cluster_ra, but I'm running into errors trying to randomly assign at the clusters using dplyr - help ie. writing a function that assigns at the cluster level then calculates/binds the difference in means (which I think I did accurately)? This is what I have:

```
data <- readRDS("../dropbox/haircolorwithY.rds")
names(data)
```

I'm trying to avoid the below

```
clust_var <- with(data, paste(hair, color, sep = "_"))
data$clust_var <- clust_var
clust <- cluster_ra(clust_var = clust_var)
head(table(clust_var, clust))
```

and use dplyr only, but the group_by is inaccurate, because it splits the data frame into clusters, but what I want to do is assign at the cluster level (ie. treat each observation like a cluster after I collapse the data) then merge that to the data (is the inner-join accurate?)

```
g1 <- function(data) {
  d1 <- data %>%
  group_by(clust) %>%
  summarise(cluster_size = n(), (mean(Y[treat == 1]) -
               mean(Y[treat == 0]))) %>%
  arrange(cluster_size) %>%
  mutate(z=sample(rep(0:1, each = n()/2), n(), replace = FALSE)) %>%
  inner_join(???, data)
  return(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you provide the cluster variable to the `cluster_ra` function in `randomizr`, you can just do

```
data <- 
data %>%
mutate(Z = cluster_ra(clust_var = clust_var))
```

there's no need to `group_by`.

NB: in `randomizr` version 0.8, `clust_var` has been deprecated in favor of `clusters`